# IIS and PHP with FastCGI/WinCache not seeing updated files

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

We have a script that regularly updates itself on a scheduled task. It downloads a ZIP, then extracts and overwrites a bunch of app files with new ones.

We're seeing many cases on IIS where the updated files aren't "seen": Display oddities or in the worst cases, errors because a "new" file has somehow included a "old" file. Restarting IIS fixes the problem.

I've tried adding explicit calls to [`wincache_refresh_if_changed`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wincache-refresh-if-changed.php) but this doesn't seem to fix it.

Does each FastCGI process use its own WinCache cache? So I'd need to refresh all of them (how?). But it seems to me that everything should "just work" since [`wincache.fcndetect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wincache.configuration.php#ini.wincache.fcndetect) is enabled.

Comment: Why not just have the update script explicitly reload the site?  I think that recycling the application pool may be all that you need to do to clear the cache, and you can definitely script that with powershell.

Comment: Same issue here. Sometimes, file changes are not detected and the old file version is executed by PHP. Any solution found?